# Get specific value of preprocessor macro

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, macros, preprocessor

In my build settings i have define some preprocessor macros

i.e. **SANDBOX_ENV=1**

I want to use the value of SANDBOX_ENV in my shell script.

I have tried echo `"SANDBOX value is = ${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS}"`

but its giving me all macros values like `DEBUG=1 SANDBOX_ENV=1 COCOAPODS=1`

I want to use value that is assigned to SANDBOX_ENV

Comment: Can you parse the literal value of ${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS} ? You could execute the literal value as a command in a shell script.  Then, the corresponding shell environment variables would be set to those values.  (can't remember the syntax off hand...)

Comment: I have no idea of shell script. Will try to search for commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="DEBUG=1 SANDBOX_ENV=1 COCOAPODS=1" 
# delete everything before our value ans stuff into TMPVAL
TMPVAL="${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS//*SANDBOX_ENV=/}" 
# remove everything after our value from TMPVAL and return it
TMPVAL="${TMPVAL// */}"
echo $TMPVAL;  #outputs 1
```

HTH,

bovako

Comment: Nice one! Any reference where can I read more on bash' `${...}` and its use with the `//` operator?

Comment: man bash :) @adib 
in the man page, search for "Parameter Expansion" to get to the correct portion;
 
       ${parameter/pattern/string}
              Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pat...

Comment: If it works @mihirmehta please mark it as an answer =) my score can use it

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to parse it easily with awk or something, but here's how I'd do it:

```
echo $GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS | grep -Po 'SANDBOX_ENV=\d+' | sed 's/SANDBOX_ENV=//'
```

In your echo context:

```
echo "SANDBOX value is $(echo $GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS | grep -Po 'SANDBOX_ENV=\d+' | sed 's/SANDBOX_ENV=//')"
```

Basically I piped the contents of GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS and grepped out the SANDBOX_ENV portion.

```
grep -P
```

is to use the Perl regex \d+, because I don't like POSIX. Just a preference. Essentially what

```
grep -P 'SANDBOX_ENV=\d+'
```

does is to find the line in the content piped to it that contains the string "SANDBOX_ENV=" and any number of digits succeeding it. If the value might contain alphanumerics you can change the \d for digits to \w for word which encompasses a-zA-Z0-9 and you get:

```
grep -Po 'SANDBOX_ENV=\w+'
```

The + just means there must be at least one character of the type specified by the character before it, including all succeeding characters that matches.

the -o (only-matching) in grep -Po is used to isolate the match so that instead of the entire line you just get "SANDBOX_ENV=1".

This output is then piped to the sed command where I do a simple find and replace where I replaced "SANDBOX_ENV=" with "", leaving only the value behind it. There are probably easier ways to do it like with awk, but you'll have to learn that yourself.

Comment: There's no need for perl mode here. `'SANDBOX_ENV=[[:digit:]]\+'` will work without it.

Comment: That's the POSIX standard which I have mentioned that I don't like. But feel free to use it. :) In fact, to replace the \w you could use [[:alnum:]].

Comment: Oh and take note that Perl mode regex \w includes the underscore '_'.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have something self contained within the Build Settings and you don't mind slight indirection, then:

1. Create User-Defined settings `SANDBOX_ENV=1` (or whatever value you want)
2. In Preprocessor Macros, add `SANDBOX_ENV=${SANDBOX_ENV}`

In your shell, to test, do

```
echo ${SANDBOX_ENV}
```

With the User-Defined Settings, you'll still be able to modify the value for Build Configuration and Architecture. So, for example, you could make the Debug config be SANDBOX_ENV=0 and Release be SANDBOX_ENV=1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Might be the obvious answer, but have you simply tried:

```
echo ${SANDBOX_ENV}
```

If that doesn't work, try using eval:

```
eval "${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS}"
echo ${SANDBOX_ENV}
```

Comment: This is potentially dangerous unless the value of `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` is guaranteed to be safe.